# Rails ActiveStorage/S3 not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

In my Rails application, I want to replace Carrierewave with Active Storage and AWS S3. In the development environment this works fine, both with an AWS_Production bucket and with an AWS_Development bucket. In the `develoment.log`, after uploading, I see:

```
Started PATCH "/users/3?locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 ...
```

In the production environment I get a `"504 gateway time-out"` from nginx.  In the production.log I don't see a `"Started PATCH ..."`. Obviously the update method is not invoked in the controller. In the nginx `error.log` I see the following:

```
2021/01/10 13:18:04 [error] 112875#112875: *26 upstream timed out 
(110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from 
upstream, client: 176.199.136.103, server: my_domain.com, request: 
"POST /users/167?locale=de HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://unix:///var/run/my_domain.sock/users/167?locale=de", host: 
"my_domain.com", referrer: "https://my_domain.com/photo_upload? 
locale=de"
2021/01/10 13:25:16 [warn] 112875#112875: *32 a client request body is 
buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000005, client: 
176.199.136.103, server: my_domain.com, request: "POST /users/167? 
locale=de HTTP/1.1", host: "my_domain.com", referrer: 
"https://my_domain.com/photo_upload?locale=de"
2021/01/10 13:26:16 [error] 112875#112875: *32 upstream timed out 
(110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from 
upstream, client: 176.199.136.103, server: my_domain.com, request: 
"POST /users/167?locale=de HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://unix:///var/run/my_domain.sock/users/167?locale=de", host: 
"my_domain.com", referrer: "https://my_domain.com/photo_upload? 
locale=de"
```